# How to write a program that will make sure that the passwords entered in both fields match?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the text "password set" to display if passwords in both fields match? What am i doing wrong? also what are the rules regarding having brackets within script? can i have two functions within the same script tag?

```
<p>First name:  <input type="text" id="fname" /></p>
<p>Surname: <input type="text" id="sname" /></p>
<p>Date of birth:   <input type="text" id="dob" /> (Please enter as dd/mm/yyyy)</p>
<button onclick="user()">Generate Username</button>
<p id="username"></p>
    <p id="match"></p>

<p>Please enter a password for your account.</p>
<p>Enter password:  <input type="text" id="password1" /></p>
<p>Re-enter password:   <input type="text" id="password2"/></p>
<button onclick="password()">Submit Password</button>

<script>
    function user() {
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = document.getElementById("fname").value+document.getElementById("sname").value+document.getElementById("dob").value.slice(-4)
    }

    function password() {
        if document.getElementById("password1").value = document.getElementById("password2").value
            document.getElementById("match").innerHTML = " Your password has been set "
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In JavaScript "=" means assignment and "==" or "===" checks for equality. Try changing "=" to "==" in your if-statement.

Comment: In password function you are using assignment operator (=) instead of equality operator (==) or the strict equality operator (===). Also missing the parentheses in the if and the { ... }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this helps :)

```js
function password(){
  var pass1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
  var pass2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
  if(pass1 == pass2){
   alert("password match");
  }else{
   alert("password do not match");
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Enter password:  <input type="password" id="password1" /></p>
<p>Re-enter password:   <input type="password" id="password2"/></p>
<button onclick="password()">Submit Password</button>
```

Comment: hi Dorian, Thanks for your reply, however this does not seem to work, nothing happens when i click Submit Password button

Comment: Dorian, this will show the message as an alert, i want the message to display as a line of text under the button

Comment: Yeah, you can simply change `alert("password match")` to `document.getElementById("match").innerHTML = " Your password has been set" ` like you did in your code :)

Comment: @SalmanTahir this is the right answer. Dorian isn't here to do all of your work. You should figure out on your own how to display the message under the button. Try to do that and open a new question if you can't manage to do it.

Comment: @SalmanTahir I suggest that you accept Dorian's answer, and then ask another question - after first giving it a go yourself. After asking the new question, come back here and post a comment underneath this answer with a reference to the new question's URL. *This is how StackOverflow works - you ask lots of questions, we give lots of answers, and each of those answers is rewarded (by you) by clicking the checkmark at top left of the best answer.*

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Thank you Doiran !